# Plaid - error_code: 'ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED'. Recurring every hour or so

Tags: plaid

I am getting the following response when calling the /accounts/balances/get endpoint in the development environment. After getting this, I'll use update mode to get a new access_token. Once I swap in the new token, everything works fine for about an hour and then this error will occur again. I am 100% not making any updates on the bank side.

{ display_message: null,
error_code: 'ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED',
error_message: 'the login details of this item have changed (credentials, MFA, or required user action) and a user login is required to update this information. use Link's update mode to restore the item to a good state',
error_type: 'ITEM_ERROR',
request_id: 'redacted',
suggested_action: null }

Comment: Were you managed to resolve this issue? What bank did you connect to?

Answer (score 0):

Does the login associated with the Item have "perpetual OTP" enabled -- i.e., is it configured so that you need to enter a 2-factor authentication token every time you log in to your bank, even on a trusted device?

If so, this is expected behavior -- once your original session expires, Plaid requires a user to be present to provide a new token and create a new session to get fresh data.

If not, there may be an issue with the integration between Plaid and the specific financial institution. If that's the situation, you should file a support ticket with Plaid so we can investigate further.

Comment: Hi Alex, no the item does not have perpetual OTP enabled. I can get in with just my normal credentials on the bank site. I'll go ahead and start a support ticket. Thank you!